# Mongoose aggregate result in custom format

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm using mongodb with mongoose and trying to reproduce this format in my callback, like this:

```
{
warning:[ {
    "_id": "5a8dcdbcadb65b484e888091",
    "application_name": "teste",
    "created_at": "2018-02-02T23:55:06.000Z",
    "log_identifier": "1"
  }, {
    "_id": "5a8dcdbcadb65b484e888091",
    "application_name": "teste",
    "created_at": "2018-02-02T23:55:06.000Z",
    "log_identifier": "1"
  }],
error:[ {
    "_id": "5a8dcdbcadb65b484e888091",
    "application_name": "teste",
    "created_at": "2018-02-02T23:55:06.000Z",
    "log_identifier": "1"
  }, {
    "_id": "5a8dcdbcadb65b484e888091",
    "application_name": "teste",
    "created_at": "2018-02-02T23:55:06.000Z",
    "log_identifier": "1"
  }]
}
```

This is my model:

```
var logSchema = new Schema({
    application_name: String,
    file_name: String,
    type: String,
    created_at: Date,
    log_identifier: String,
    environment: String
 });
```

I'm setting type and group by type using aggregate method, like this:

```
LogModel.aggregate([
        {
            "$unwind": "$type"
        }, {

            $group: {
                "_id": {
                    type: "$type"
                },

                "Warning": {

                    "$push": {
                        "$cond": {
                            if: {
                                $eq: ["$type", "Warning"]
                            },
                            then: {
                                "_id": "$_id",
                                "application_name": "$application_name",
                                "created_at": "$created_at",
                                "log_identifier": "$log_identifier",
                                "enviroment": "$enviroment"
                            },
                            else: false,
                        }
                    }
                },
                "Error": {

                    "$push": {
                        "$cond": {
                            if: {
                                $eq: ["$type", "Error"]
                            },
                            then: {
                                "_id": "$_id",
                                "application_name": "$application_name",
                                "created_at": "$created_at",
                                "log_identifier": "$log_identifier",
                                "enviroment": "$enviroment"
                            },
                            else: false,
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    ], function (err, logs) {
        if (err) reject(err);
        else resolve(logs)
    });
```

but my result is

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
     "type": "Error"
    },
    "Warning": [
  false
],
 "Error": [
   {
     "_id": "5a8dd312c681334d558e6169",
     "application_name": "teste",
     "created_at": "2018-02-02T23:55:06.000Z",
     "log_identifier": "1"
   }
 ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "type": "Warning"
    },
    "Warning": [
      {
        "_id": "5a7b6a36a5799090cf76bc4c",
        "application_name": "teste",
        "created_at": "2018-02-02T23:37:06.000Z",
        "log_identifier": "1"
      },
      {
        "_id": "5a7b6a49a5799090cf76bc4d",
        "application_name": "teste",
        "created_at": "2018-02-02T23:55:06.000Z",
        "log_identifier": "1"
      },
      {
        "_id": "5a8dcdbcadb65b484e888091",
        "application_name": "teste",
        "created_at": "2018-02-02T23:55:06.000Z",
        "log_identifier": "1"
      }
    ],
    "Error": [
      false,
      false,
      false
    ]
  }
]
```

I don't want fields with false values and I cannot know other method to reproduce what I want.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your aggregation as below in 3.4 version.

[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) by type and push the values for each type. [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) with [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) to output the named keys.

```
LogModel.aggregate([
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$type",
    "data":{
      "$push":{
        "_id":"$_id",
        "application_name":"$application_name",
        "created_at":"$created_at",
        "log_identifier":"$log_identifier",
        "enviroment":"$enviroment"
      }
    }
  }},
  {"$replaceRoot":{
    "newRoot":{
      "$let":{
        "vars":{"array":[["$_id","$data"]]},
        "in":{"$arrayToObject":"$$array"}}
    }
  }}
])
```